# Error When executing a sql statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, select, sql-server-2012

When i am trying to execute the following command i get the following output error.

```
("INSERT INTO Leaves (EmpID,TotalLeavesRemaining,Year)
      SELECT EmpID,TotalLeavesRemaining,'" + year + "'
      FROM Leaves
      WHERE Year = '" + yearbefore + "' ", con)
```

Additional information: Conversion from string

> INSERT INTO Leaves (EmpID,TotalL" to type 'Double' is not valid.

When i run the command directry through the sql management studio the query does its job !

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You need to use Parameters not concatenating the sql string - could leaves you open to sql injection attacks and the datatype will be assessed for you.

Comment: What is the datatype of Year, is it double while you are trying to handle it like string?

Comment: ...also ticks are not a general purpose SQL field delimiter; using SQL Parameters will prevent datatype conversions

Comment: If you put single quotes around your year number it makes it a string. But apparently your year column is of type double. (Why? Shouldn't' it be of type `int`?). Remove the single quotes!

Answer (score 0):

If you put single quotes around your year number it makes it a string. But apparently your year column is of type double. (Why? Shouldn't' it be of type int?). Remove the single quotes!

And also use command parameters. This makes it safer, less error prone and also faster, as the SQL-Server can cache the query and reuse it without having to recompile it and to create an execution plan again.

```
using (var cmd new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Leaves (EmpID, TotalLeavesRemaining, Year)
                                SELECT EmpID,TotalLeavesRemaining, @year
                                FROM Leaves
                                WHERE Year = @yearbefore", con)) {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", 2015);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearbefore", 2014);
    ...
}
```

Note that you don't need any quotes around parameters, even for string parameters. They free you from escaping strings, formatting numbers and dates.

If you want to use multiline strings, use verbatim strings introduced with an `@`. These string literals can span multiple lines and don't interpret the backslash (`\`) as an escape character. Single quotes can be escaped by double single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to concatenate SQL string then convert your year to string or join using `&` instead of `+`

```
("INSERT INTO Leaves (EmpID,TotalLeavesRemaining,Year)
      SELECT EmpID,TotalLeavesRemaining,'" + year.ToString + "'
      FROM Leaves
      WHERE Year = '" + yearbefore.ToString + "' ", con)
```